# Swift Wait for Callback to finish before method return

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I'm using Siesta REST API client for swift. I'm logging into an external API (successfully) and get the result from the siesta request object. The request has two callbacks - onSuccess and onFailure.

If the login was successful I set a token in the keychain and then return the result to the view controller - which segues to a new view controller if successful.

However, as I'm assuming the callback is used asynchronously, my function is not returning the correct result.

```
 @IBAction func normalLoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //do normal login
    let standardLogin = StandardLogin()
    let credentials = ["email" : "john@example.com", "password": "password" ]
    let loginResult = standardLogin.login(params: credentials)
    print(loginResult)
    if loginResult {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSuccessfulLoginView", sender: self)
    }

 }

 func login(params : Dictionary<String,String>) -> Bool{
    var loginSuccess = false
    let loginRequest = wrApi.makePostRequest(route: "login", params:params)

    loginRequest
        .onSuccess { data in
            print("succes")
            self.setJwtToken(jsonData: data.content)
            loginSuccess = true
        }
        .onFailure { error in print("an error occured")
    }


    return loginSuccess

}
```

My question is basically how do I wait for the callback to finish before returning my loginSuccess Boolean?

I'm pretty new to swift, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

login is acsync function, so you can't use return 
Try closure:

```
   func login(params : Dictionary<String,String>, handleFinish:((isOK:Bool,param: Type?)->())){
       var loginSuccess = false
    let loginRequest = wrApi.makePostRequest(route: "login", params:params)

    loginRequest
        .onSuccess { data in
            print("succes")
            self.setJwtToken(jsonData: data.content)
            loginSuccess = true
            handleFinish(isOK: true, param :data.content )
        }
        .onFailure { error in 
                       print("an error occured")
                        handleFinish(isOK: false, param :nil )
    }

   }
```

and call it:

```
login(param) { (isOK, param) in
  if isOK{
   print("login success: \(param)")
 }
```

}

Comment: This seems to resolve my issue - need to have a quick read up about how this works though - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As @Nguyen points out, you can't return an immediate value from an async function.  Given that all you're doing with the return value is performing your segue - just move that call into the completion handler

```
@IBAction func normalLoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //do normal login
    let standardLogin = StandardLogin()
    let credentials = ["email" : "john@example.com", "password": "password" ]
    standardLogin.login(params: credentials)
}


func login(params : Dictionary<String,String>){
    let loginRequest = wrApi.makePostRequest(route: "login", params:params)

    loginRequest
        .onSuccess { data in
            print("success")
            self.setJwtToken(jsonData: data.content)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSuccessfulLoginView", sender: self)
    }
        .onFailure { error in print("an error occured")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russell - chose Nguyen's answer just because I wanted to keep the performSegue func separate.